# setInterval on click event to run for 10 seconds

Tags: javascript, time

I have a piece of JavaScript I want to run every 100 ms for 10 seconds when a user clicks an element on the page.

I have it working to an extent but if a users click on the element a second time it no long runs.

Any help would really be appreciated.

**CODE**

```
jQuery('.pager .pages li, .pager .pages li a').click(function(){
    var safariClearFixTimer = setInterval(safariClearFix ,100);
    setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( safariClearFixTimer ); }, 10000);
    function safariClearFix(){
        jQuery('.itemgrid-3cols .item').css('cssText', 'clear: none !important;'); 
        console.log('COUNT');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe clear the interval each time the element is clicked before setting it ?
Something like this :

```
var safariClearFixTimer;
var timer;
jQuery('.pager .pages li, .pager .pages li a').click(function(){
    clearInterval( safariClearFixTimer );
    clearTimeout( timer );
    safariClearFixTimer = setInterval(safariClearFix ,100);
    timer = setTimeout(function( ) { clearInterval( safariClearFixTimer ); }, 10000);
    function safariClearFix(){
        jQuery('.itemgrid-3cols .item').css('cssText', 'clear: none !important;'); 
        console.log('COUNT');
    }
});
```

**[edit]**
By the way, you should also clear the timeout on click or you're probably gonna have some unexpected behaviours.
**[edit2]**
Added clearTimeout in the code above

Comment: Did you try clearing the timeout as well ? (i edited my post)

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable the button when you start the interval and enable it again when you clear it. Try this [JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/vozipufado/2/edit?html,js,console,output)

For your application, it would also be a good idea to change the css of the button so the user knows that it is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get the setInterval approach to work so I solved it with a different approach.

I used javaScript DOMSubtreeModified event to apply my changes on modifications to the DOM.

```
    jQuery('body.catalog-category-view .main.container .col-main, body.catalogsearch-result-index .main.container .col-main').on("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
        jQuery('.itemgrid-3cols .item').css('cssText', 'clear: none !important;');
    });
```